# Pause movement of a image with keyboard and enable again

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class called animacionPacman that has keyevents for moving the pacman with the Keyboard. I want to implement a pause method that makes the pacman wait when the space bar is pressed, and continue when that key is pressed again. I tried to make a thread but I'm a novice in java. The program has no errors, but the pacman doesn't move.
Here is some code:

```
class MiThread extends Thread {
    private AnimacionPacman p;

    public MiThread(AnimacionPacman p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        p.move();
    }
}

Public class Scenario extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private MiThread hilo;
    animacion = new AnimacionPacman();
    hilo = new MiThread(animacion);

    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            animacion.keyReleased(e);
        }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        hilo.start();         
        animacion.keyPressed(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need multithread at all, just capture keys: move key? move it -- space bar? ok put a boolean variable to true and stop the game cycle if it's true.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you're going about to implement this but don't worry it's very simple!  You have a KeyAdapter, and if a key is pressed pac man moves.  You want to override (redefine that version you have) a method from KeyAdapter called keyReleased, that stops pac man.

I won't write it out in code because I think trying it out yourself will provide benefits to you, but your two options are to have 1 key (say the right arrow) make Pacman move right when pressed, and stop when that same key (right arrow) is released.  Your second option is to have right arrow move Pacman right on right arrow keyPressed, but have the spacebar stop him on keyPressed.  My own opinion is that it is more intuitive to have the release of a key stop the character than to have a separate key control stopping that a different key started.

Common to both approaches is the need for a stop() method, just as you have a move() method.  Again, depends on your implementation on how you're moving the character around, but generally the keyRelease() will cause movement speed to be set to 0.